# Whois scraping bash script—if clause errors

Tags: bash, whois

I wrote a fairly straightforward script to map out what one-word domains are still available. I'm getting an error in line 7, the if clause, but I can't see anything wrong with it.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat /usr/share/dict/words);
do
        i="$i.com"
        echo $i processing `date`
        if [ $(whois $i) == "*No match for*" ]
        then
                echo $i AVAILABLE
#               echo "$i">>domains.available.`date "+%Y%m%d"`
        else
                echo $i unavailable
#               echo "$i">>domains.unavailable.`date "+%Y%m%d"`
        fi
done
```

I looked up similarly straightforward scripts online, and they seem syntactically identical.

Comment: Side remark: the absence of a WHOIS record does not necessarily imply that a domain is available.

Comment: Oh, sure; it just provides a starting point to begin manual enquiries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double brackets and the * outside the quotes

```
if [[ $(whois $i) == *"No match for"* ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote the argument:

```
if [ "$(whois $i)" == "*No match for*" ]
```

Otherwise all the words of the response will be split into separate arguments to the `test` command.

Or you could use the built-in conditional operator. It doesn't do word splitting of variables or command substitutions.

```
if [[ $(whois $i) == "*No match for*" ]]
```

Comment: The latter (double-brackets for the built-in conditional operator) does in fact resolve the error, but silently gives me false negatives consistently. In other words, `$i=notarealdomainatall.com` still flows to the else block.

Comment: Are you expecting `==` to do a pattern match instead of an exact match? Wildcards inside quotes are not considered pattern characters.

Comment: Ah, yes I was! '*No match for*' is an unlikely literal string to result from a whois query ;-)